# Simple open source paint program

Tags: c, open-source, gtk, paint

I am trying to experiment with expanding paint-like program adding custom features to it. Can you suggest a simple open source paint-like program written in C and using GTK+ library which I could expand? It should compile in Linux but also in Windows (using MinGW). Thanks.

EDIT:

I found [this](http://mtpaint.sourceforge.net/) and it looks like something I was looking for, but I want something more simple if it exists.

Comment: I would like to answer GIMP, but that is hardly "simple" ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very example paint using GTK+ http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk_tut-23.html

source code: http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk_tut-30.html#ss30.3

I hope this help you and someone else

Answer (score 3):

I never had this urge, but my 4 year old daughter loves [TuxPaint](http://www.tuxpaint.org/). I believe it uses GTK+.

Comment: nice, but it looks too fancy :) I want something very simple, like paper and pen with colors and maybe little more... sorry I was not precise in asking

Comment: @kliketa, TuxPaint IS very simple.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something *really* simple, I think following [the official scribble tutorial](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/2.17/c2424.html) would be the best choice. Here is a [link](http://git.gnome.org/cgit/gtk+/tree/examples/scribble-simple/scribble-simple.c) to the resulting code: you can find it in the GTK+ source tarball under examples/.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to the Multimedia -> Graphics -> Editors section of the Sourceforge software browser, sorted in descending order of most active:

http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap/trove_list.php?stquery=&sort=percentile&sortdir=desc&offset=0&form_cat=106

Just click on "Filters" and add a programming language filter for C and you should get a nice concise set of results for what you're looking for.